# Xcode 6.1 NSConstraint run around

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

Before I upgraded Xcode to 6.1 this worked just fine:

```
    var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.viewContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation(rawValue: 0)!, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0);
```

Now I get the error:

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:', expected 'item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:**positiveSuffix**:constant:')

So if I change the function call to look like:

```
var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.viewContentView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation(rawValue: 0)!, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, positiveSuffix: 1.0, constant: c);
```

Then I get the error message:

> Incorrect argument label in call (have 'item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:positiveSuffix:constant:', expected 'item:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:**multiplier**:constant:')

The NSLayoutConstraint constructor look like:

```
        NSLayoutConstraint(item: <#AnyObject#>, attribute: <#NSLayoutAttribute#>, relatedBy: <#NSLayoutRelation#>, toItem: <#AnyObject?#>, attribute: <#NSLayoutAttribute#>, multiplier: <#CGFloat#>, constant: <#CGFloat#>)
```

So the constructor uses the parameter name 'multiplier', but the build fails when I use that and it tells me to use the parameter name 'positiveSuffix'. When I switch to using 'positiveSuffix,' the build fails again and tells me to use the parameter name 'multiplier.'

Anyone have any ideas, or is this simply a bug?

Comment: replacing NSLayoutRelation(rawValue: 0)! with NSLayoutRelation.Equal works for me. I don't know about those weird error messages though.

Comment: @rdelmar beat me to it as usual - I was going to suggest replacing that rawValue thing with the actual value - that's probably confusing the compiler. Is there a reason you're using that? Was that a problem in earlier versions?

Comment: rdelmar, did you use Xcode 6.1?
I tried using .Equal, but I still get the same error messages.

jrturton, this worked before I upgraded to Xcode 6.1

Comment: I didn't think to try this before, but I just created a new project in Xcode 6.1, and the constructor worked. Something must have gone wrong with the upgrade for my project.

Comment: My answer was deleted by a moderator (don't know why, maybe i should have posted it in the comments), anyway...Are you using XCode Simulator for iPhone 5s, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6s?! If yes, switch your target to iPhone5 or lower...This solved the issue for me (xcode bug?!)